# How do I figure out what version of Ubuntu I have?

Tags: versions

How do I figure out what version of Ubuntu I have?  Is there a command I can use in terminal?  Thank you for any help.  I am an extreme newbie.

Comment: `cat /etc/lsb-release`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat /etc/lsb-release`

```
natasha@natasha-M51SE:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
```

Comment: @elektron10 If this answer worked for you, please accept it with the checkmark on the left to thank the user and let others know, this was to correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

try `lsb_release -a`. Example:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: This command is correct but gives too much information in `LSB Version`.